In the Wikipedia page on the lambda cube, is the side condition on the Start rule necessary?
The Start rule says
$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash A\colon s\quad x\mbox{ does not appear in }\Gamma}{\Gamma, x\colon A \vdash x\colon A}.$$
The side condition seems to be enforcing linearity, but the Weakening rule
$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash A\colon B \quad \Gamma \vdash C\colon s}{\Gamma, x\colon C \vdash A\colon B}$$
allows deriving contexts with multiple copies of $x:$
$$\frac{\frac{\Gamma \vdash A\colon s\quad x\mbox{ does not appear in }\Gamma}{\Gamma, x\colon A \vdash x\colon A} \quad \Gamma \vdash A\colon s}{\Gamma, x\colon A, x\colon A \vdash x\colon A}.$$
Why, then, have the side condition?

The wikipedia rules do not even appear sound. Consider this special case of the weakening rule
$$\frac{Γ ⊢ x : B \quad Γ ⊢ C : s}{Γ,x:C ⊢ x : B}$$
With the start and abstraction rules, we can deduce
$$x : B ⊢ (λx. x) : C → B$$
which seems like a problem if $C$ and $B$ are distinct.
The one problem I can think of that the condition on the start rule prevents is when $A$ refers to a previous $x$ in the context. In such a case
$$Γ, x : A ⊢ x : A$$
would capture the $x$ in the second occurrence of $A$, which likely would not make much sense. But, they forgot that the weakening rule can do a similar capture.
You don't have to have side conditions that prevent shadowing to avoid variable capture. But with dependent types it is possible that you may be able to locally refer to something whose type mentions the shadowed variable, so you'd need some way of disambiguating which variable with the same name is meant locally.

In both of these lecture notes, the weakening rule also has the side condition, which enforces the linearity condition:
https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/summerschool/summer23/_lectures/oplss-lambda-cube3.pdf
https://groups.seas.harvard.edu/courses/cs252/2016fa/15.pdf
But I think that means that terms where variables shadow each other can't be typed directly, e.g. $\lambda x\colon B. \lambda x\colon A.x.$  Instead I guess you have to do alpha substitution.
